# Command Line zsh bad assignment error when setting an Alias

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal, alias

In my mac terminal, I am running the following command and getting the following error.

```
(base) jgeorge ~ % alias pip = 'python3 -m pip'
>>> zsh: bad assignment
```

When i try editing my `.zshrc` file with the same line of code, I get the same error when I refresh my terminal. Not really sure what is going wrong here. I tried changing the alias to a different word but the error persists

Comment: Remove the spaces before and after the equal sign.

Comment: wow it was that easy! Thanks @accdias

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZSH/Shell variable assignment/usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168043/zsh-shell-variable-assignment-usage)

Comment: Added the above answer as a reference, in case you want to know more about environment variables and aliases. You can think of aliases like environment variables when setting them.

Comment: As usual, the best answer is in a comment to the question. Thanks @accdias. That was exactly my issue.

Answer (score 9):

Please see this post for how to resolve this issue: https://itsfoss.com/solve-zsh-bad-assignment/. TL;DR, no spaces around the `=` in your aliases. This fixed it for me, but I set mine manually and edited them manually.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open the file /Users/me/.zshrc [this is the file where you were trying to add the path for Python]
2. Look for the line that is missing a '', and add that ''. [most likely it's going to be the line you added with Python], so look there first.
3. Save your file and exit.
4. then in your terminal, run this command: `source ~/.zshrc` this will refresh your .zshrc file.