# How to set local variable in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I was trying to set variable in terminal, for example we use to store this variable in .env config file in different scenario and sometimes in xml or yml file but here I want to store them locally

because my am facing error for the following command

```
HTTP_PORT = 3002 P2P_PORT = 5002 PEERS = ws://localhost:5001 npm run dev
```

I am using Mac zsh terminal.

Comment: You can add something like `export HTTP_PORT=3002` to the file .zshrc. Either open a new terminal or `source ~/.zshrc`to reload your current shell to activate the changes.

Comment: What do you mean by **local** variable here? In zsh, a local variable is one which only lives during the execution of a function. It is set using `local NAME=VALUE`.

Comment: Aside from this, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168043/zsh-shell-variable-assignment-usage) similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
export KEY=value
export HTTP_PORT ="3002"
echo $HTTP_PROXY
```

This might help you but remember each time you close your terminal it will erase this data.

Reference [HERE](https://linuxhint.com/set-environment-variable-zsh/)